# References regards complex analysis on Banach spaces

Tags: complex-analysis, banach-spaces

I'm looking for a references on complex analysis in Banach spaces. What are good books on this subject?
Any help is welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should clarify if you want analysis on complex Banach spaces (i.e. complex vector space instead of real vector space) or analysis on complex Banach spaces/manifolds (if such a thing even exists).  
Complex analysis is a bit ambigious in this context

Comment: @F. Conrad Maybe even analysis on C*algebras. These are new things for me.

Comment: Now I am intrigued if such a thing exists as well.